# reverse a string in html

Tags: javascript, html

I know this sounds simple, but I'm looking to incorporate a line of javascript into a bit of html. The javascript code is

```
String.prototype.reverse=function(){
            return this.split("").reverse().join("");
        }
```

The html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>7.23</title>
    <meta charset= "utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <p><label>Input
        <input type = "text" id = "s" size = "25">
        </label>
    </p>
    <input type = "button" id = "r" value = "Reverse" onclick="String.prototype.reverse(this);">
    <p id = "t"></p>
    <script>
        var s = document.getElementById("s").value;
        String.prototype.reverse=function(){
            return this.split("").reverse().join("");
        }
        document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = String.prototype.reverse(s);
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Any help?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://eddmann.com/posts/ten-ways-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of misconceptions with your code.

First lets fix the "Reverse" button to call the proper element:

```
<input type = "button" id = "r1" value = "Reverse" onclick="String.prototype.reverse(this);">
```

To this:

```
<input type = "button" id = "r" value = "Reverse"
       onclick="document.getElementById('t').innerHTML = document.getElementById('s').value.reverse();">
```

The first code is explicitly calling the prototype function passing in a reference to `this` (which is a reference to a button, not the text you were wanting).

The second line calls a new prototype function as an extension of the `s` element's value (i.e. the text in the text box), and assigns it to the `p` element's inner HTML directly.

Next we need to adjust your script function to be just the prototype function.
The original script was calling `document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = String.prototype.reverse(s);` after the element was loaded in page, so the value of `s` was empty (since it just loaded), and that function was never being called again to readjust the inner HTML of the `p` tag.

The new script could be just the following:

```
<script>
    String.prototype.reverse=function(){
        return this.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
</script>
```

Now here's the complete HTML (with a few more adjustments to the tags):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>7.23</title>
    <meta charset= "utf-8">
    <script>
        String.prototype.reverse=function(){
            return this.split("").reverse().join("");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <label for="s">Input</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "s" size = "25">
    </p>
    <p id = "t"></p>
    <input type = "button" id = "r" value = "Reverse"
           onclick="document.getElementById('t').innerHTML = document.getElementById('s').value.reverse();">
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that can help.